# How to destroy objects properly so they are not causing memory leakage

Tags: memory-leaks, asp-classic, vbscript

When I create two dictionary objects that are referencing each other, they stay in memory even after I set them explicitly to nothing. The following code consumes >1 GB of memory

```
Dim i
For i = 1 to 100000
    leak
Next

Sub leak

    Dim a, b
    Set a = createObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set b = createObject("scripting.dictionary")

    a.Add "dict1", b
    b.Add "dict2", a

    Set a = Nothing
    Set b = Nothing

end sub
```

This is not related to some garbage collecting (VBScript does not do that). Proof: when I change `a.Add "dict1", b` to `a.Add "dict1", "foo"` and `b.Add "dict2", a` to `a.Add "dict2", "bar"` the memory consumptions stays within reasonable limits.

By the way, this also occurs when a dictionary is referencing itself:

```
Sub leak
    Dim a
    Set a = createObject("scripting.dictionary")
    a.Add "dict1", a
    Set a = Nothing
end sub
```

Is it possible to destroy objects like these cross referencing dictionaries in a way that they are also destroyed in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer for dictionaries: Use the `RemoveAll` method to get rid of all keys and values before the references get out of scope. Tested it and no leakage:

```
Sub leak

    Dim a, b
    Set a = createObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set b = createObject("scripting.dictionary")

    a.Add "dict1", b
    b.Add "dict2", a

    a.RemoveAll
    b.RemoveAll

end sub
```

This also solves the circular reference problem if you use dictionaries as `keys` (instead of `items`/`values`) like:

```
a.Add b, "dictionary b"
b.Add a, "dictionary a"
```

Answer (score 1):

First read [Eric Lippert's article (Explanation #2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx), then change your code to

```
Dim i
For i = 1 to 100000
    leak
Next

Sub leak

    Dim a, b
    Set a = createObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set b = createObject("scripting.dictionary")

    a.Add "dict1", b
    b.Add "dict2", a

    Set a("dict1") = Nothing
    Set b("dict2") = Nothing

end sub
```

The refcounts of `a` and `b` are decremented by leaving the sub scope, for `a("dict1")` and `b("dict2")` you must do it yourself.

Comment: Nice article! And thanks to this I found the solution: use `x.RemoveAll` to remove all keys before letting the dictionary out of scope, I'll post the solution next.